# How to match Cyrillic characters with a regular expression

Tags: regex, unicode, character-properties

How do I match French and Russian Cyrillic alphabet characters with a regular expression?  I only want to do the alpha characters, no numbers or special characters.  Right now I have

[A-Za-z]

Comment: Look in this question: [Regex and unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389/regex-and-unicode)

Comment: Here it is: [А-Яа-я]

Comment: @AlexErygin For Russian only characters it is: **`[ЁёА-я]`** (where `А` is Russian). The unicode code for Russian `а` is right after `Я`, so you don't need 2 ranges. The unicode codes for `Ёё` is not between `А-я` so you need to specify Ёё separately.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It depends on your regex flavor. If it supports Unicode character classes (like .NET, for instance), `\p{L}` matches a letter character (in any character set).

Comment: How about doing this in Java?

Comment: This will match **any** Cyrillic characters including those not present in the Russian alphabet (Greg was asking about Russian Cyrillic)

Comment: In Javascript, you need to also add the flag 'u'. See https://javascript.info/regexp-unicode.

Comment: Note: p{L} from JavaScript doesn't work in Safari at the moment.

Answer (score 67):

If your `regex` flavor supports **Unicode blocks** (`[\p{IsCyrillic}]`), you can match **Cyrillic** characters with:

```
[\p{IsCyrillic}] or [\p{Cyrillic}]
```

Otherwise try using:

```
[U+0400–U+04FF]
```

For `PHP` use:

```
[\x{0400}-\x{04FF}]
```

**Explanation:**

```
[\p{IsCyrillic}]

Match a character from the Unicode block "Cyrillic" (U+0400–U+04FF) «[\p{IsCyrillic}]»
```

---

**Note:**

Unicode Characters list and Numeric HTML Entities of [`[U+0400–U+04FF]`](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0400.pdf) .

Comment: This thread explains that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926514/matching-cyrilic-symbols-in-c-sharp

Comment: @black Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using PHP.

Comment: For `php` try using `[\x{0400}-\x{04FF}]` instead. https://regex101.com/r/zcRenT/1

Comment: PHP supports `\p{Cyrillic}`, you just need to make sure to add a u flag onto the regex

Answer (score 32):

To match only **Russian** Cyrillic characters use:

```
[\u0401\u0451\u0410-\u044f]
```

which is the equivalent of:

```
[ЁёА-я]
```

where `А` is Cyrillic, not Latin. (Despite looking the same they have different codes)

`\p{IsCyrillic}`, `\p{Cyrillic}`, `[\u0400-\u04FF]` which others suggested will match [all variants of Cyrillic](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0400-04FF), not only Russian

Answer (score 11):

If you use modern PHP version - just:

```
preg_match("/^[\p{L}]+$/u");
```

Don't forget the **u** flag for unicode support!

Comment: Can you explain your regex please? I tried it with `Бори́с` but it does not match, so your regex does not work.

Comment: It's easy, please look at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php
"L" means any letter.
So the "и́" symbol should be in some other group! Try to find it.

Answer (score 6):

Regex to match cyrillic alphabets with normal(english) alphabets :

```
^[A-Za-z.!@?#"$%&:;() *\+,\/;\-=[\\\]\^_{|}<>\u0400-\u04FF]*$
```

It matches special chars,cyrillic alphabets,english alphabets.

Comment: Non-English alphabets are not normal ??? Not to mention there is only 1 English alphabet

Answer (score 5):

Various regex dialects use `[:alpha:]` for any alphanumeric character in the current locale. (You may need to put that in a character class, e.g. `[[:alpha:]]`.)

Comment: This works in PostgreSQL too, but matches all national characters (so not only current locale). And you can also use `[[:lower:]]` and `[[:upper:]]` for matching specific case. E.g. replace lower case characters: `regexp_replace(firstname, '[[:lower:]]', 'a', 'g')`.

Answer (score 5):

this worked for me

```
[a-z\u0400-\u04FF]
```

Comment: to match ONLY Cyrillic characters use `[\u0400-\u04FF]`

Answer (score 2):

If you use Elixir:

```
String.match?(string, ~r/^\p{Cyrillic}*$/u)
```

You need to add the `u` flag for unicode support.

Comment: Attention, the above regex returns `true` for empty String: `String.match?("", ~r/^\p{Cyrillic}*$/u)` => `true`. You should change `*` modifier for `+` to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the first and the last letter. For example in Bulgarian:

```
[А-я]+
```

Answer (score 0):

For modern PHP ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12026487/1907888)):

```
$string = 'тест тест Тест Обязателльно Stackoverflow >!<';
var_dump(preg_replace('/[\x{0410}-\x{042F}]+.*[\x{0410}-\x{042F}]+/iu', '', $string));
```

Answer (score -2):

In Java to match Cyrillic letters and space use the following pattern

```
^[\p{InCyrillic}\s]+$
```