# Regex pattern including all special characters

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a simple regular expression to check if in given string exist any special character. My regex works but I don't know why it also includes all numbers, so when I put some number it returns an error.

My code:

```
//pattern to find if there is any special character in string
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.-^*()%!]");
//matcher to find if there is any special character in string
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(searchQuery.getSearchFor());

if(matcher.find())
{
    errors.rejectValue("searchFor", "wrong_pattern.SearchQuery.searchForSpecialCharacters","Special characters are not allowed!");
}
```

Comment: the dash in `[]` should be escaped, it has special meaning there.

Comment: Exactly. It would be better to define all "non-special" charactes and make that negative.

Comment: yes maybe it would be wiser to assert the use of only those characters you want to allow.

Comment: Can you please provide the solution String.replace("\"", "&quot;")

Comment: To easily do live tests of your regex patterns, I would suggest this very useful tool : https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 280, accepted):

Please don't do that... little Unicode [`BABY ANGEL`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f47c/index.htm)s like this one  are dying! ◕◡◕ (← these are not images) (nor is the arrow!)

## ☺

And you are killing 20 years of DOS :-) (the last smiley is called [`WHITE SMILING FACE`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/263a/index.htm)... Now it's at `263A`... But in ancient times it was `ALT-1`)

and his friend

## ☻

[`BLACK SMILING FACE`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/263b/index.htm)... Now it's at `263B`... But in ancient times it was `ALT-2`

Try a negative match:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9]");
```

(this will ok only `A-Z` "standard" letters and "standard" `0-9` digits.)

Comment: @AbdullahShoaib Clearly not :) You'll need to do a full list of what you consider "special" and/or what you consider "good".

Comment: I notice many people use `[A-Za-z0-9]` to represent any letter or digit, both lowercase and upper, but is it not better to just do `[0-z]`?

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon:  The decimal digits, the upper case roman letters, and the lower case roman letters occupy three _disjoint_ ranges of character code space.

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon You can see what James wrote in the handy screenshot of Character Map posted by Sina in another response: your regex would accept *:;<=>?@[\]^_`* (other than 0-9, a-z, A-Z)

Comment: @AbdullahShoaib to handle non-english letters correctly, it's better to use `[^\p{Alnum}]`

Comment: Lets assume that we use [A-Za-z0-9] , but if we need to take care about Cyrillic or a few more alphabets, than how to do the regex?

Comment: @KaloyanStamatov See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256825/cyrillic-alphabet-validation

Comment: there are more languages than English ...

Answer (score 51):

You have a dash in the middle of the character class, which will mean a character range. Put the dash at the end of the class like so:

```
[$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-]
```

Comment: Can you  please provide the solution  String.replace("\"", "&quot;");

Comment: @LovaChittumuri Please state your problem clearly. What are you trying to achieve, input, and desired output.

Answer (score 33):

That's because your pattern contains a `.-^` which is all characters between and including `.` and `^`, which included digits and several other characters as shown below:

[image]

If by special characters, you mean punctuation and symbols use:

```
[\p{P}\p{S}]
```

which contains *all unicode* punctuation and symbols.

Answer (score 31):

SInce you don't have white-space and underscore in your character class I think following regex will be better for you:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^\\w\\s]");
```

Which means match everything other than `[A-Za-z0-9\s_]`

Unicode version:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{L}\\d\\s_]");
```

Answer (score 18):

For people (like me) looking for an answer for special characters like Ä etc. just use this pattern:

- Only text (or a space): "[A-Za-zÀ-ȕ ]"
- Text and numbers: "[A-Za-zÀ-ȕ0-9 ]"
- Text, numbers and some special chars: "[A-Za-zÀ-ȕ0-9(),-_., ]"

Regex just starts at the ascii index and checks if a character of the string is in within both indexes [startindex-endindex].

So you can add any range.

Eventually you can play around with a handy tool: https://regexr.com/

Good luck;)

Comment: Just the stuff I looked for. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 16):

Use this to catch the common special characters excluding `.-_`.

```
/[!"`'#%&,:;<>=@{}~\$\(\)\*\+\/\\\?\[\]\^\|]+/
```

If you want to include `.-_` as well, then use this:

```
/[-._!"`'#%&,:;<>=@{}~\$\(\)\*\+\/\\\?\[\]\^\|]+/
```

If you want to filter strings that are URL friendly and do not contain any special characters or spaces, then use this:

```
/^[^ !"`'#%&,:;<>=@{}~\$\(\)\*\+\/\\\?\[\]\^\|]+$/
```

When you use patterns like `/[^A-Za-z0-9]/`, then you will start catching special alphabets like those of other languages and some European accented alphabets (like é, í ).

Answer (score 14):

Shout out to [Mohamed Yusuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56593871/20262198) 's solution!

We can match all 32 special characters using range.

```
[!-\/:-@[-`{-~]
```

#### 1st Group

##### **[!-\/]**

- Match ASCII code from 33 to 47:
- !"#$%&'()*+,-./

-- 15 out of 32 characters matched

#### 2nd Group

##### **[:-@]**

- Match ASCII code from 58 to 64:
- :;<=>?@

-- 7 out of 32 characters matched

#### 3rd Group

##### **[[-`]**

- Match ASCII code from 91 to 96:
- [\]^_`

-- 6 out of 32 characters matched

#### 4th Group

##### **[{-~]**

- Match ASCII code from 123 to 126:
- {|}~

-- 4 out of 32 characters matched

In total matched back all 32 chars (15+7+6+4)

###### Reference

[Special Character table_Arranged](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/specchar.htm)

[Extended ASCII table](https://www.ascii-code.com)

Answer (score 10):

I have defined one pattern to look for any of the ASCII Special Characters ranging between 032 to 126 except the alpha-numeric. You may use something like the one below:

> **To find any Special Character:**
>
> ```
> [ -\/:-@\[-\`{-~]
> ```
>
> **To find minimum of 1 and maximum of any count:**
>
> ```
> (?=.*[ -\/:-@\[-\`{-~]{1,})
> ```

These patterns have Special Characters ranging between 032 to 047, 058 to 064, 091 to 096, and 123 to 126.

Answer (score 8):

Here is my regex variant of a special character:

```
String regExp = "^[^<>{}\"/|;:.,~!?@#$%^=&*\\]\\\\()\\[¿§«»ω⊙¤°℃℉€¥£¢¡®©0-9_+]*$";
```

(Java code)

Answer (score 6):

Use this regular expression pattern ("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$") .It validates alphanumeric string excluding the special characters

Answer (score 5):

If you only rely on ASCII characters, you can rely on using the hex ranges on the ASCII table. Here is a regex that will grab all special characters in the range of `33-47`, `58-64`, `91-96`, `123-126`

```
[\x21-\x2F\x3A-\x40\x5B-\x60\x7B-\x7E]
```

However you can think of special characters as *not* normal characters. If we take that approach, you can simply do this

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+
```

Hower this will not catch `_` `^` and probably others.

Comment: I finally used `(?i)^([[a-z][^a-z0-9\\s\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}\\\\^\\$\\|\\?\\*\\+\\.\\<\\>\\-\\=\\!\\_]]*)$` to match any character.

Comment: **Never use `[A-z]` in a regex.** It matches all uppercase and lowercase ASCII letters as you would expect. but it also matches several punctuation characters whose code points lie between `Z` and `a`.  Use `[A-Za-z]` instead, or `[a-z]` in case-insensitive mode.

Comment: @AlanMoore, good to know! I'll make the change to the answer.

Comment: how about '.' dot character . It supporsed to match any character except new line. In python re.DOTALL matches all including newline. Check out the regular expression faq in the python tutorial https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
(?i)^([[a-z][^a-z0-9\\s\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}\\\\^\\$\\|\\?\\*\\+\\.\\<\\>\\-\\=\\!\\_]]*)$
```

`(?i)^(A)$`: indicates that the regular expression `A` is case insensitive.

`[a-z]`: represents any alphabetic character from `a` to `z`.

`[^a-z0-9\\s\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}\\\\^\\$\\|\\?\\*\\+\\.\\<\\>\\-\\=\\!\\_]`: represents any alphabetic character except `a` to `z`, digits, and special characters i.e. accented characters.

`[[a-z][^a-z0-9\\s\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}\\\\^\\$\\|\\?\\*\\+\\.\\<\\>\\-\\=\\!\\_]]`: represents any alphabetic(accented or unaccented) character only characters.

`*`: one or more occurrence of the regex that precedes it.

Comment: Inside a character class, none of those characters need to be escaped except `\` and `-`.  Many of them never need to be escaped at all.  "Better safe than sorry" is a fine philosophy, but readability is important, too.

Comment: @AlanMoore (If you're the comic book author, extra credit), the "-" I've found can be left unescaped if left as the trailing character.  `[a-z_=-]` matches a-z, _, =, or -.  I place readability above all else in anything of the form "regex", but yeah, using the shortcuts can lead to woes eventually.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this for the same things - `StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(value)`

Comment: space/blank is also a special char if you use this method. Better to replace the space and tabs chars before calling this method.

Answer (score 3):

We can achieve this using Pattern and Matcher as follows:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(trString);
boolean hasSpecialChars = matcher.find();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my regular expression, that I used for removing all the special characters from any string :

```
String regex = ("[ \\\\s@  [\\\"]\\\\[\\\\]\\\\\\\0-9|^{#%'*/<()>}:`;,!& .?_$+-]+")
```

Comment: Perfectly worked for me but small change is that to escape '\' (backslash) we should use "\\\\\\\\"

Answer (score 3):

Please use this.. it is simplest.

> \p{Punct} Punctuation: One of !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(checkstring);
    String regex = "\\p{Punct}"; //Special character : `~!@#$%^&*()-_+=\|}{]["';:/?.,><
    //change your all special characters to "" 
    Pattern  pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(builder.toString());
    checkstring=matcher.replaceAll("");
```

Comment: this answer matches the common list of special characters used by (american?) login systems.
https://support.okta.com/help/s/article/What-special-characters-are-accepted-by-the-Okta-password?language=en_US

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative match:

`Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9])*");`
(For zero or more characters)

or

`Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9])+");`
(For one or more characters)

Comment: Question is not about allowing only roman numerals and english alphabets, what if user wanted to except japanese text, your solution is not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works on C# it should work on java also. If you want to exclude spaces just add \s in there
 `@"[^\p{L}\p{Nd}]+"`

Answer (score 1):

**To find any number of special characters use the following regex pattern:**
**([^(A-Za-z0-9 )]{1,})**

[^(A-Za-z0-9 )] this means any character except the alphabets, numbers, and space.
{1,0} this means one or more characters of the previous block.

Comment: It won't find `(` and `)`.

Comment: The `(` and `)` are problematic here.  `[^A-Za-z_=]`, for example, allow for anything other than A-Z or a-z or _ or = to trigger.  `[^[:alnum:][:punct:]]` similarly triggers on any character not alphanumeric nor punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers helped for me. Found this regex `/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$/` from [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-string-consists-only-of-special-characters/) and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

(^\W$)

^ - start of the string,
\W - match any non-word character [^a-zA-Z0-9_],
$ - end of the string

Answer (score 0):

A small addition to include all special characters like: `ū` and `Ā`:

An example:

```java
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ū]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape some symbols

```
/([!`\-\_.\"\'#%,:;<>=@{}~\$\(\)\*\+\/\\\?\[\]\^\|]+)/
```

OR

```
/([\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\>\=\?\@\[\]\{\}\\\\\^\_\`\~]+$)/
```

Answer (score 0):

To match the **common Ascii special characters** you can simply use this `[!-\/]`.

So, it will be `Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[!-\/]");`

Answer (score 0):

what about `[ -~]`
This will match all ASCII characters from the space to tilde

Answer (score -1):

I use reg below for find special character in string

```
var reg = new RegExp("[`~!@#$%^&*()\\]\\[+={}/|:;\"\'<>,.?-_]");
```