# Does regex special character allowing security break?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

My regex looks like this.

```
    if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9~@#$^*()_+=[\]{}|\\,.?: -]*$/", $text) == FALSE) {
      echo 'Wrong!'
    }
```

I want to allow special characters ' and " sign too. How should I better implement it? And whether it is a security break for mysql database.

Comment: What do you mean by "security break"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex pattern including all special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057962/regex-pattern-including-all-special-characters)

Comment: I mean that does it will not allow some sql injection vulnerability open if I let such characters as ' or others to be inserted into database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell me exactly what characters and symbols you want to enable in the field? I will edit the regex.. Basically it should look like this:

```
$yourString = "blahblah";
if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_-]*$/', $yourString)) {
    #your string is good!
}
else {
    #your string is wrong.
}
```

Comment: I want a till z, A till Z, 0 till 9 and all special characters which are on keyboard ~ ` ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + = - } { | " : , . / \ ? ; '

Comment: use /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g

Comment: Use `/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&'"*)\]\[(+=._-].*/`

Comment: Does ' and " can't be implemented as allowed?

Answer (score 1):

SQL injection is best prevented by escaping anything that comes from the user.  Without such,

```
WHERE x = '$x'
```

with $x being

```
' OR true OR '
```

turns into

```
WHERE x = '' OR true OR ''
```

thereby letting the hacker in without knowing the right value for `x`.  Variants of this hack allow really nasty things to happen.

Escaping would give

```
WHERE x = '\' OR true OR \''
```

which will suitably fail, and the hacker will move on to another way to break through your defenses.