# Creating pattern for literal characters, special character and "+"

Tags: java, regex

I try to create pattern for literal characters, couple of special character and `+` without success.

I used this as the example [Regex pattern including all special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057962/regex-pattern-including-all-special-characters)
This my regex but according to http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html the string `+` is not matches:

```
[a-zA-Z\x43-_#@.:;/\\=!^() ]+
```

What I missed?

Comment: Why do you have `\x43`? Ans `+` is not even part of your character class

Comment: the ASCII value of `+` is 0x2B or decimal 43. Why don't just use `\+`?

Comment: What about `[a-zA-Z\x43-_#@.:;/\\=!^() +]+` ?

Comment: You can use: `[a-zA-Z_#@.:;/\\\\=!^() +-]+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the `-` at the end, otherwise `\x43-_` means anything between ASCII of `C` and ACSII of `_`:

```
[a-zA-Z\x43_#@.:;/\\=!^() +-]+
```

Regex101 tells us that before, the `-` meant:

```
\x43-_ a single character in the range between C (ASCII 67) and _ (ASCII 95) (case sensitive)
```

And if you move it to the end:

```
=!^() +- matches a single character in the list =!^() +- (case sensitive)
```

And the `+` can be used as a literal inside a character group.
The `\x43` is for `C`, so I think you mixed up the ASCII code here, just remove it and use `+` as a literal.

Answer (score 2):

43 is **decimal** ASCII code for `+`.

But you wrote `\x43-_` which means: a **range** of chars between
`C` (**hexadecimal** 43) and `_`.

I suppose, you wanted here not any range but just 3 literal characters:

- plus,
- minus,
- underscore (`_`).

If this is the case, change this fragment to `+\-_` (plus can be given as is,
"literal" minus between `[` and `]` requires quoting with a `\`,
and undescore can be left as is).

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex it should work:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "[a-zA-Z_#@.:;\\/\\\\=!^() +-]+";
final String string = "+";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
         System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```