# JQ - how to define regex for special characters

Tags: regex, string, jq

I have a JSON string and am trying to remove all the special characters
(i.e. those defined by the regex `[!@#$%^’&*(),.?":{}|<>]`)
from it.

Some of the jq expressions I've tried are as follows:

```
sub("[!@#$%^’&*(),.?":{}|<>]"; "") 

sub("/[!@#$%^’&*(),.?":{}|<>]/g"; "")

sub("/\W|_/g"; "")
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Use `gsub(_;"")` or `sub(_;"";"g")` where _ is a jq expression evaluating to the relevant JSON string specifying the regex.

Since _ must be a jq expression, the jq escaping rules for strings apply, e.g. to escape double quotes, use `\"`. String interpolation is also allowed.

So in the present instance, _ could be:

```
"[!@#$%^’&*(),.?\":{}|<>]"
```

---

See also the jq docs and [Regex pattern including all special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057962/regex-pattern-including-all-special-characters/18058217)

Comment: the docs: `sub(regex; tostring) sub(regex; string; flags)` be the smart guy ...

Comment: can you provide example of yours? can't execute it anyway ...

Answer (score 0):

The final working solution:

```
tags: (.title
      | sub("([!@#$%^’&*(),.?|])"; ""; "g")
      | split(" ")
```

and, escaping the apostrophes or single quotes (if needed):

```
tags: (.title
      | sub("([!@#$%^’'"'"';:&*(),.?|])"; ""; "g")
      | split(" ")
```

Comment: In jq, to escape double quotes, use `\"`. jq does not require one to escape single quotes.  Your shell of course may complicate things, e.g. in bash: `jq -nr $'"\'"'`