# How can I check if the last char of a string is a punctuation mark or a special character (#,+,*....) [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, string, char, contains

I know how to code the problem.
My problem is to find a list that contains all the special characters there are.

Maybe there's a method im missing out on that has all special characters.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057962/regex-pattern-including-all-special-characters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)