# FILTER + REGEXMATCH + REGEXREPLACE including all special characters in a case sensitive analysis

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, regex-replace

In cases specific special characters could be added as follows:

```
=FILTER(D1:D, REGEXMATCH(D1:D, "^("&REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A:A),"([().])","\\$1")&")$")=FALSE)
```

But when wanting to analyze all of them, [the best approach would be a negative match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18058074/11462274), fetching all the different values of `A-Z`, `a-z`, and `0-9`.

So, I tried to reproduce it with a direct addition that finds the values but when matching the values, it returns the number of matches to zero:

```
=FILTER(D1:D, REGEXMATCH(D1:D, "^("&REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A:A),"([^A-Za-z0-9])","\\$1")&")$")=FALSE)
```

What is the correct approach in this case?

[Google Sheets data with expected result](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NJ1JONggshRYJRQoAcJykze2b6x0jbF5JnupUTGNqYc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do you have sample data with expected results? Btw, `([^A-Za-z0-9])` is better written like `[\W_]`, any non-word character *or* underscore. Also, if not captured you can refer to `\\$0`.

Comment: hello @JvdV , sorry for not putting the spreadsheet link, I completely forgot.

Comment: Been looking at the desired results but I cant yet figure out the rules why that is the desired results.

Comment: Hi @JvdV I'm looking for values that are in column D but not in column A.

Comment: I thought I had an answer but I'm still confused with the expected results (your explaination in the sheet). Are you looking for case-sensitive matching as well?

Comment: @JvdV Yes, I'm filtering out the values that exist in column D but don't exist in column A, taking into account any differences, including uppercase or lowercase letters, accents, punctuation, and special characters.

Comment: Then, why is 'Toronto FC' from D:D in your desired results when clearly it is in column A:A with extra '*' being the only difference. Basically all of your examples are found in column A:A?

Comment: Because ```Toronto FC``` is different to ```Toronto * FC``` @JvdV (means that the team name has changed in the database, so from now on it will no longer appear as ```Toronto * FC``` but as ```Toronto FC```) and this is how I will need to officially use it from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=FILTER(D1:D, 
  REGEXMATCH(D1:D, 
    "^("&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 
      REGEXREPLACE(A:A,"[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]","\\$0"))&")$")=FALSE)
```

Regular expression of all special characters: `[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]`

#### Reference:

[Escaping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#escaping)