# Regular expression to include all languages characters in the first name in js

Tags: javascript, regex, wcs

I want to add functionality for user to add First name or Last name in any language for Eg. Spanish, French and Chinese.
Right now I am using this RegEx:

```
var firstNameRegex  = /^[a-zA-Z\u3000\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FFF\u00C0-\u017F\-\'\s]{1,45}$/;
```

But this is only working for English Alphabets When I am trying to add French characters like

```
à- â - ä- é - è - ê - ë - ï - î - ô -ö - ù - û - ü- ÿ-ç
```

Then i am getting error.

Any suggestions.

Comment: https://javascript.info/regexp-unicode

Comment: You could use the \p{L} tag from javascript to match any letter from any language

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex pattern including all special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057962/regex-pattern-including-all-special-characters) Tested one of the answer's patterns in there `[A-Za-zÀ-ȕ]` and it matches all the characters you've listed perfectly fine.

Comment: No this doesn't answer the question

Comment: @icecub that solution wont work when you try to include more languages in like Chinese and so on

Comment: @KaranShishoo Yup, I agree. Your solution is more useful in this case.

Comment: `\p{Alphabetic}` is more universal than `\p{L}`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
 var firstNameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F\u3000\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FFF\-\'\s]{1,45}$/;
```

Or this if only whitespaces are not valid:

```
var firstNameRegex = /^(?=.*\S)[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F\u3000\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FFF\-\'\s]{1,45}$/
```

please see this regex [cheatsheet](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)

```js
document.getElementById('nameForm').onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var firstNameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F\u3000\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FFF\-\'\s]{1,45}$/;
    var input = document.getElementById('firstNameInput').value;

    if (firstNameRegex.test(input)) {
        alert("'" + input + "' is a valid name.");
    } else {
        alert("'" + input + "' is NOT a valid name.");
    }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Regex Name Validation</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Enter a First Name</h2>

<form id="nameForm">
  <input type="text" id="firstNameInput" placeholder="First Name">
  <button type="submit">Check Validity</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the regex unicode groups, you can test for all common used letters.

`\p{L}` or `\p{Letter}` contains the matching-information for all defined unicode symbols that represent a letter.

For a list of the matching unicode symbols, you can take a look at https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category. Everything in the categories starting with L, matches `\p{L}`. These are Lowercase Letter, Modifier Letter, Other Letter, Titlecase Letter, Uppercase Letter.

By using the modifier `u` for unicode, these groups (`\p{GroupName}`) will be parsed and you get the expected result.

```js
let list = [
  "Sören",
  "Jürgen",
  "Téa", 
  "Váquéz", 
  "Garciá", 
  "Zöe",
  "Eleña",
  "Double-Name",
  "强", // examples from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_given_name
  "秀英",
  "Number 5",
  "Emoji ",
  "Some ",
];

list.forEach(firstName => console.log(
  firstName,
  /^[\p{L}\-'\x20]{1,45}$/u.test(firstName)
));
```

I would not recommend using the meta-character `\s` in this use case, as it matches multiple white-space characters: space character (`\x20`), tab character (`\x09`), carriage return character (`\x0D`), new line character (`\x0A`), vertical tab character (`\x0B`), form feed character (`\x0C`)

More information about the unicode groups can also be found on:

- https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category
- https://javascript.info/regexp-unicode#unicode-properties-p

Comment: wouldnt this aproach be unsafe for mathematical letters ? since they are also in a letter group ? like  would return true ?

Comment: @jakubpodhaisky yes as it would find them too. -- OP doesn't ask for exclusion of unwanted letters. OP asked for any kind of letters. -- I added also an example.