# Matching Cyrillic symbols in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a huge file of code with many lines like this:

```
Enterprise::TextMessageBox::Show(String::Format(S"Възникнал е проблем:\n\n{0}", e->Message), S"Грешка");
```

What i`m trying to do is to find every part of the code with string of cyrilic symbols with another text that i provide. My problem is that i cant seem to make good enought expressions so i can catch the lines.
Another problem is that some times the lines contain only one such string but other times they contain 2 or more on one line.

Every such string is similar and it look like this:

```
S"some cyrilic symbols"
```

I tried to make it with Regex class but I can't seem to make good enough pattern to the strings.

Comment: Dude dont tell me what my program is... the strings i`m looking for are from managed c++ actually but i`m typing application to do the task i need in C# so please dont change my tags!

Comment: You're trying to script this, or to use the Find in Files dialog to get a list of occurrences in the code? In any case, what is the problem if there are two instances on the same line?

Comment: I`m loading a text that is read line by line and i want to replace all the lines containing this strings with another strings that i select and save the new file. But whatever patter i try it does not find any lines.

Comment: You're right, excuse me, i red the question wrong

Comment: Which part are you trying replace: the text, or the code?  If you're trying to replace the code, it might be much simpler to look for matching quotes rather than for what is between the quotes.  Can you please edit your question to show a sample of what you're trying to look for **and** what you're trying to replace it with?  And if there are lines you don't want to match, an example of those would be helpful too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK you have the possibility to match for Unicode properties. Try something like this

```
Regex TheRegex = new Regex(@"S""[\p{IsCyrillic}\p{P}\p{N}\s]*""");
```

`\p{IsCyrillic}` matches any cyrillic character

`\p{P}` is the unicode category for punctuation

`\p{N}` is the unicode category for a number in any language

`\s` matches a whitespace

[See here on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#CategoryOrBlock) for more infos about unicode categories and here on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to open you file in one of these three ways, It depends how it was save, but for me the rule is that `string` is unicode, so these reading encode natives characters to unicode, and then `Regex` should work.

```
    /* Open OEM File*/ 
FileStream f1 = new FileStream(@"..\..\Datas\TestOEM.txt",FileMode.Open);
StreamReader sw1 = new StreamReader(f1,
    Encoding.GetEncoding(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage));
string a = sw1.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(a);
sw1.Close();
f1.Close();

  /* Open Unicode file */
FileStream f2 = new FileStream(@"..\..\Datas\TestUNICODE.txt",FileMode.Open);
StreamReader sw2 = new StreamReader(f2,Encoding.Unicode);
string b = sw2.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(b);
sw2.Close();
f2.Close();
  /* Open ANSI file */

FileStream f3 = new FileStream(@"..\..\Datas\TestANSI.txt",FileMode.Open);
StreamReader sw3 = new StreamReader(f3,Encoding.Default);
string c = sw3.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(c);
sw3.Close();
f3.Close();
```

You can loop and use regular expression

```
Regex reg0 = new Regex(@"Възникнал е проблем",
                         RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (reg0.IsMatch(string from file)){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regexp:-

```
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"YourReplacementText",
    RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Here we check the Match instance.
if (match.Success)
{
    // Do your stuff
}
```

**input** -  this is your cyrilic input string

**YourReplacementText** - this is your cyrilic replacement string

**RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase** - represents this regular expression, ignore the case and checks for multiline too.

## Short notation for Regexp:

```
/Грешка/gim
```

**Грешка** - change this text to your desired text for replacement/matching purpose

**i** - represents ignorecase

**m** - represents multiline

**g** - represents global, for iterative matching

Comment: You are missing the main point, the OP wants to match strings with ANY cyrillic letters and not a specific word.