# preg_match with cyrillic text

Tags: php, string, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to match Cyrillic characters with a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716609/how-to-match-cyrillic-characters-with-a-regular-expression)

I have a simple php script which uses preg_match to compare a string against some cyrillic text inside a  variable (e.g. $var = 'страница').

However when I input the cyrilic text into the variable it comes up as ???????? in my code.

```
$var1 = '/?????????????/';
```

I  get the folowing warning when I run the script:

`preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0`

Can anyone suggest a solution?
thanks very much.

Comment: I always recommend this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 1):

Change encoding of your scripts or all project source files on UTF for example in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Use modifier for unicode

```
preg_match('/abcdef/u',$some_string)
```

Maybe it’s because of invalid codepage, which codepage has your interpreter and which codepage uses connection to a database (if any?)

Comment: That `u` stands for `UTF-8`, not Unicode. We don't really know what encoding the OP is using.