# how to make regular expression match only Cyrillic bulgarian letters

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I want to replace all the letters from bylgarian alphabet with empty string 
I've seen this link
[How to match Cyrillic characters with a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716609/how-to-match-cyrillic-characters-with-a-regular-expression)
but it doesn't work for me

Here is what I've tried

```
1. var newstr = strInput.replace(/[\p{IsCyrillic}]/gi, '');
```

doesn't work!

```
2. var newstr = strInput.replace(/[\p{Letter}]/gi, '');
```

also nothing
thanks for help;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Javascript doesn't support Unicode classes of the form `\p{IsCyrillic}`.

But, assuming the characters you want to replace are in the Unicode [Cyrillic](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0400-04FF) range 0400 - 04FF, you could use:

```
newstr = strInput.replace( /[\u0400-\u04FF]/gi, '' );
```

For example:

```
    var strInput = 'уфхцчшщъhelloЁЂЃЄрстыьэю',
        newstr = strInput.replace( /[\u0400-\u04FF]/gi, '' ); 

    console.log( newstr );    //  'hello'
```

Comment: thanks it  works! Do you know afunction which will get all of thw special characters #@ +-+>etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think that JavaScript RegEx does not support this syntax.

May be this will help?

[XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
Pattern.compile("[А-я]+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).matcher(strInput ).replaceAll("") ;
```

Where `[А-я]+` is your alphabet.