# Replace func doesn't recognize cyrillic character when used with /b

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, cyrillic

I have been struggling with this issue for quite some time, the code works fine with latin chars, as for cyrillic, jquery don't recognize it at all.

```
$('p').each(function() {   var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.text().replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, "<span>$1</span>"));  
});
```

I have also tried the following code, but for some reason, jQuery skips every second word and doesn't wrap it :(

```
$(this).html($(this).text().replace(/\s([a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+)\s/g, " <span> $1 </span> "));
```

Any hint?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659594/how-to-make-regular-expression-match-only-cyrillic-bulgarian-letters

Answer (score 0):

It appears JS isn't so good at this (as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659594/how-to-make-regular-expression-match-only-cyrillic-bulgarian-letters) by @Rolice in the comments above).  In most languages, you merely need to change the locale.

You may have to do something like this:

```
replace(/(^|[^\w\u0400-\u04FF])(\w+)([^\w\u0400-\u04FF]|$)/,
  "$1<span>$2</span>$3");
```