# JS check if string contains only cyrillic symbols and spaces

Tags: javascript

I have some string and I need to check if this string:

a) consists of 3 words
b) contains ONLY cyrillic symbols and spaces

My code:

```
var isValid;
isValid = function(s) {
  return s && s.split(" ").length === 3 && /[а-яА-Я ]/.test(s);
};
```

But this code doesn't work, because isValid('a b c') returns 'true'. What is my mistake? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716609/how-to-match-cyrillic-characters-with-a-regular-expression) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var isValid = function(s) {
    return s && s.split(" ").length === 3 && /^[\u0400-\u04FF ]+$/.test(s);
};
```

Comment: Here is a quick explanation on using unicode character classes. You need unicode hex codes for your regex. I looked up Cyrillic, found it here: http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0400.pdf. Cyrillic characters go from 0x0400 to 0x04FF. In regex, use \u followed by the 4-character code: \u0400, \u04ff. Make that a character class and you're off. More info here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html