# How to validate russian letters?

Tags: java, validation

How can I validate the Russian language?
If I start and use russian, I'll receive:
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 4
^[а-ЯА-Яa-zA-Z ]+$

```
private Pattern onlyLetter = Pattern.compile("^[а-ЯА-Яa-zA-Z ]+$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE) ;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716609/how-to-match-cyrillic-characters-with-a-regular-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\p{IsAlphabetic}` is regular expressions in Java, which is **Unicode-aware** and can check if the characters are **alphabetic**.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html, *«Classes for Unicode scripts, blocks, categories and binary properties»*