# JavaScript Regex: Remove text between parentheses, brackets and cyrillic character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Would it be possible to change

`(Test 1 / Test 2) [Test 3] Отдел / Here is title - subtitle (by Author) - 1234 (5678-9999), descriptions (best), more descriptions`

to

`Here is title - subtitle (1234) (descriptions)`

using JavaScript with Regex?

Currently, I have to combine multiple replace functions, like below

```js
let text = '(Test 1 / Test 2) [Test 3] Отдел / Here is title - subtitle (by Author) - 1234 (1234-4567), descriptions (best), more descriptions';

text = text
  .replace(/ *\([^) ]*\) */g, "")
  .replace(/ \([\s\S]*?\)/g, '')
  .replace(/[0-9`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');

console.log(text);
```

But it doesn't working as expected. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is the input string ***always*** in the same format, ie. are the parentheses, slashes, dashes etc. in the same place, in every instance?

Comment: And does  output `(1234)` come from `1234` or first part of `(1234-4567)`

Comment: for cyrillic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716609/how-to-match-cyrillic-characters-with-a-regular-expression

Comment: And what is `(descriptions)` in the result supposed to be, based on `descriptions (best), more descriptions`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, it always in the same format

Comment: @mplungjan it comes from `1234`

Comment: @CBroe I need to put descriptions inside parentheses

Comment: But _which part_ of `descriptions (best), more descriptions`?

Comment: @CBroe This part `descriptions (best)`

Comment: It's not pretty, but... https://regex101.com/r/wiGEIE/1

Comment: @SamWhan It doesn't work

Comment: Please update the question with concrete step by step requirements: 1) remove substrings between `[` and `]`, 2) .... 3) wrap the part after/betwee with parentheses, etc. to make the question answerable. Right now, "Remove text between parentheses, brackets and cyrillic character" just warrants a `.replace(/\([^()]*\)|\[[^\][]*]|[\u0400-\u04FF]+/g, '')` (like [here](https://regex101.com/r/wav6yX/1)), but it does not provide the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Entering this as an answer to "prove" that it works ;)

But, as I said in comment, it's not pretty. There must be a better way.

Anyway, what it does is to consume (match) everything inside the first parenthesis pair with `\([^)]*\)`. After that  it matches everything up to `/`  (inclusive) with `[^/]*?\/\s*` (made the first part there non greedy which it wasn't originally). Then it captures the title, up to  `(`, with `([^(]*?)\s*\(`. After that it's time to match up to `1234`. Done with `[^)]*\)\s*-\s*`.

Time to capture `1234` with `(\d+)` (I'm assuming it's always a number, otherwise you need to replace it with something lik `([^)]*)`.

Math up to the description with `\s*\([^)]*\),\s*` and capture it with `(.*?)\s\(` (the `\s\(` is to not get it in the capture group).

Finally match the rest with `.*$` (not really necessary, but... :)

Replace all this with `$1 ($2) ($3)` to get parentheses in the right places. Voila :D

```js
let text = '(Test 1 / Test 2) [Test 3] Отдел / Here is title - subtitle (by Author) - 1234 (1234-4567), descriptions (best), more descriptions';

console.log(text.replace(/^\([^)]*\)[^/]*?\/\s*([^(]*?)\s*\([^)]*\)\s*-\s*(\d+)\s*\([^)]*\),\s*(.*?)\s\(.*$/gm, '$1 ($2) ($3)'));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but it works for specific case. I'm trying to make it works for some cases