# Check if the first letter that appears in the string is Cyrillic or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to check if the first letter in a string is a Cyrillic letter.

Here is what I have until now, but the problem is that if the string starts with a digit it also fires the pattern:

```js
$(document).on('keydown keyup', '#userBox', function() {
  $('#result').html('');
    if (/[a-zA-Z]*[^A-Za-z \d]+[a-zA-Z]*/.test(this.value)) {
      $('#result').html('Cyrillic');
    } else {
      $('#result').html('Non-Cyrillic');
    }
    if ( $(this).val().length === 0) {
          $('#result').html('');
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="userBox" autocomplete="off" type="text"  autofocus="true" placeholder="Type your message"> <span id="result"></span>
```

also using the solution from this post [How to match Cyrillic characters with a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716609/how-to-match-cyrillic-characters-with-a-regular-expression)
will produce the same result

```js
$(document).on('keydown keyup', '#userBox', function() {
  $('#result').html('');
    if (/[\p{IsCyrillic}]/.test(this.value)) {
      $('#result').html('Cyrillic');
    } else {
      $('#result').html('Non-Cyrillic');
    }
    if ( $(this).val().length === 0) {
          $('#result').html('');
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="userBox" autocomplete="off" type="text"  autofocus="true" placeholder="Type your message"> <span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: So, all you want to is to match the first Cyrillic letter? `if (/^\p{Script=Cyrl}/u.test(this.value))`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That will not do it... I want to apply the rule only to the first letter that appears in the string. So, this `234 test` should be Latin and this `234 тест` should be Cyrillic, although, both start with a number.

Comment: Ok, `if (/^\P{L}*\p{Script=Cyrl}/u.test(this.value))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/^\P{L}*\p{Script=Cyrl}/u
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/FG3BQe/1).
Note the `/u` flag that makes it possible to use Unicode property/category classes inside ECMAScript 2018+ compliant regular expressions. *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\P{L}*` - zero or more chars other than letters
- `\p{Script=Cyrl}` - a Cyrillic char

```js
$(document).on('keydown keyup', '#userBox', function() {
  $('#result').html('');
    if (/^\P{L}*\p{Script=Cyrl}/u.test(this.value)) {
      $('#result').html('Cyrillic');
    } else {
      $('#result').html('Non-Cyrillic');
    }
    if ( $(this).val().length === 0) {
          $('#result').html('');
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="userBox" autocomplete="off" type="text"  autofocus="true" placeholder="Type your message"> <span id="result"></span>
```

**Bonus**:

To make sure the first char of a string is a Cyrillic char use

```js
/^\p{Script=Cyrl}/u
```

If you want to support leading optional whitespaces before the first char of a string that is a Cyrillic char:

```js
/^\s*\p{Script=Cyrl}/u
```

Comment: thanks for the well-explained solution. Prety much to learn from it!