# Handling danish special characters

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

I am trying to parse a string, split it on what is not a letter or number

```
$parse_query_arguments = preg_split("/[^a-z0-9]+/i", 'København');
```

and construct a mysql query.
Even if I skip the preg_split and try to enter the string directly it breaks it into 2 different strings, 'K' and 'benhavn'.

How can I deal with these issues?

Comment: Use a different character set... like `utf-8` ...  [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using literal characters like `a-z` then it won't match accented ones. You might want to use the various [character classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) available to do more generic matching:

```
/[[:alpha:][:digit]]/
```

The `[:alpha:]` set is much broader in scope than `a-z`. Remember character matching is done based on character code, and `a-z` in order take, literally, characters between `a` and `z` by index. Characters like `ø` lie outside this range even if they'd fall between that alphabetically.

Computers work in ASCII-abetical (UNICODEical?) order.

Answer (score 1):

This might help explain what is going on in your regex... [Regex and Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389/regex-and-unicode).

You could try something like `\p{L}` as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716609/how-to-match-cyrillic-characters-with-a-regular-expression)

Comment: I am a bit lost here, how should I use this? In a replace funcion?