# How to find urdu words in a string using python

Tags: python, regex

I have lot of files that contains urdu and english. I have to search for those words that are in urdu only. For english, I know its not a problem by using regular expression. `r'[a-zA-Z]'` But How I can use regular expression for urdu language.

Suppose this is the string

```
test="working جنگ test  بندی کروانا not good"
```

Please guide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389/regex-and-unicode

Comment: "Please solve it and guide?" . Do you also want a coffee?

Comment: Since not every StackOverflow user know the alphabet of Urdu language, you should at least specify the list of characters you want to consider to be part of an Urdu word, plus possible accent (if applicable).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Applying [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389/regex-and-unicode) to urdu using [this information](http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Urdu.html) it would seem that this is the solution:

> Indian-arabic digit codepoints: `U+0660 - U+0669`
>
> Arabic letter codepoints: `U+0600 - U+06FF`

**In python3 this is really easy:**

Use this expression:

```
r'[\u0600-\u06ff]'
```

Example:

```
>>> test="working جنگ test  بندی کروانا not good"
>>> test
'working جنگ test  بندی کروانا not good'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'[\u0600-\u06ff]',test)
['ج', 'ن', 'گ', 'ب', 'ن', 'د', 'ی', 'ک', 'ر', 'و', 'ا', 'ن', 'ا']
```

By adding a `+` once-or-more operator, you can get complete words.

```
>>> re.findall(r'[\u0600-\u06ff]+',test)
['جنگ', 'بندی', 'کروانا']
```

**Update for python 2.7 working**

In python 2.x unicode is difficult. you have to prefix the regex with `ru` to mark it as unicode then it will find the correct glyphs. Also your first line in the script should be

```
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
test=u"working جنگ test  بندی کروانا not good"
myurdu="".join([unicode(letter) for letter in re.findall(ur'[\u0600-\u06ff]',test)])
print myurdu
>>> 
جنگبندیکروانا
```

For more information I refer you to [declaring an encoding](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) and [unicode support in python](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). Consider switching to python3 because unicode support is mmuch better there if you are going to handle a lot of urdu.

Comment: Isn't `[\u0660-\u0669]` already included in `[\u0600-\u06ff]`?

Comment: I folowed above but it is printing only english word and none urdu ?

Comment: Yes I tried both but it is showing only english. my python version is 2.7.6

Comment: This is the result of  print re.findall(r'[\u0600-\u06ff]',test)
['o', 'r', 'k', 'i', 'n', 'g', 't', 'e', 's', 't', 'n', 'o', 't', 'g', 'o', 'o', 'd']

Comment: No sir, Its difficult as I have to change many other things also

Comment: @Shafiq pass the pattern as unicode as well: `ur'[\u0600-\u06ff]+'`

Answer (score 0):

Another Style of solving your problem

```
import re    
test=u"working جنگ test  بندی کروانا not good"
token=test.split(' ')
for w in token:
  status=re.search(ur'[\u0600-\u06ff]+',w)
  if status:
      print w
```

It should work for python version 2.7